# polylines for multiple locations

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simple Polylines</title>
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>


function initMap() {
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 3,
center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
 });
 var lat1=[37.772,37.772];
  var lng1=[-122.214,-122.214];
  var lat2= [-27.467,67.999];
  var lng2= [-153.027,-126.788];
 for(var i=0; i<lat1.length; i++)
{
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
{lat: lat1[i], lng: lng1[i]},

{lat: lat2[i], lng: lng2[i]}
];
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: flightPlanCoordinates,
geodesic: true,
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 2
 });

flightPath.setMap(map);

 }
 }

</script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB3wFd2SjiCAqbFrm8GgeZJ0RuGHSguDSQ&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

this is my code to draw polylines  between different start and end points. This works fine. Now i need to integrate this with my angular code which get data from my database.

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 angular.module('myApp', []).controller('orderCtrl',   function($scope,$http,$interval){


load_userrequest();



function load_userrequest(){
    console.log("in angular user request view");
$http.get('http://localhost:3001/bill').success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
        $scope.users=data;
});
};

});
```

How do i integrate these codes? I want to include my initMap function after $scope.users=data. When i do that i get a error saying window.init is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The below converted AngularJS example shows how to read coordinates from an external endpoint:

```js
angular.module('mapsApp', [])
.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {

  $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });


  $http.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vgrem/61352c9edea7bec8d1e0/raw/20673c41c76cfffdb827d65a363b8ba4b0fc15e7/flightPlanCoordinates.json')
  .success(function(data) {

    data.forEach(function(coords){
  
      var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
         path: coords,
         geodesic: true,
         strokeColor: '#FF0000',
         strokeOpacity: 1.0,
         strokeWeight: 2
      });
      flightPath.setMap($scope.map);
    });
      
  });

});
```

```css
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map_div {
    height: 600px;
  }
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
  <div id="map_div"></div>
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/87xNTz5ArBV7IJmY9ioY?p=preview)